# how to retrive form.serialize() data in laravel controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I use `$("form").serialize()` to submit form data. while I return value from a method it works fine. My method code is as below.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $list = @$request['lists'];
    $total_amount = @$request->total_amount;
    $r_g_amount = @$request->r_g_amount;
    $type = @$request->type;
    $cash = @$request->cash;
    $credit = @$request->credit;
    $bank = @$request->bank;
    $from = @$request->from;
    $to = @$request->to;
    return $cash;
  }
```

it sends me null value, if I `return $request->formdata` then it sends me all details of form. `formdata` is variable which I pass from `ajax` as `formdata:$("form").serialize()`.

so how can I get values of form data into `variable`.

ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('HK.store') }}",
    data: {
       lists: list, total_amount: total_amount, formdata : $("form").serialize(), "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
 });

enter code here
```

Comment: You have to use $request->all() to retrieve all posted data

Comment: You could use JSON.stringify(form.serializeObject()), then use the JSON middleware mentioned here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-validate-json-input-using-requests?page=1

Comment: it sends me unnecessary data

Answer (score 6):

Use below code in your controller function of Laravel,

```
    $box = $request->all();        
    $myValue=  array();
    parse_str($box['formdata'], $myValue);
    print_r($myValue);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: sorry bro my system got crashed , but i have used formdata:$("form").serialize() with post ajax method, and get the data with above code. and it is working fine.

Comment: @HirenMangukiya have you tried exploding the string and then parsing it like `parse_str(explode("?", $box['formdata'])[1], $myValue);`

Comment: @linktoahref thanks for your suggestion your code is not work for me but `explode` works.

Comment: By far the best and the simplest solution. 
It worked for me in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code  like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $list = $request->lists;
    $total_amount = $request->total_amount;
    $r_g_amount = $request->r_g_amount;
    $type = $request->type;
    $cash = $request->cash;
    $credit = $request->credit;
    $bank = $request->bank;
    $from = $request->from;
    $to = $request->to;

   return response(['cash' => $cash]);
  }
```

Comment: again it sends null value

Answer (score 0):

When you are using dynamic post data you have to be sure that variables exists. So here is an example how to get variables you need:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $list = array_get($data, 'list', 'default value');
    $total_amount = array_get($data, 'total_amount', 0);
    ...
    return $whatever;
}
```

Comment: @HirenMangukiya maybe you didn't send them to the backend? Show us the js request please

Comment: @HirenMangukiya try to add `dataType: 'json'` in ajax

Comment: @HirenMangukiya can you attach screenshot of network tab of devtools with this request that you made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143506/discussion-between-hirenmangukiya-and-alex-slipknot).

Comment: Please check chat room i attach photo there

Comment: @HirenMangukiya in the screenshot I saw that your post is GET instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your serialized formData into Object first and then send it to your server:

```
const clientInfo= $('#checkoutForm').serialize();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(clientInfo);
clientInfo = Object.fromEntries(searchParams);// { 'type' => 'listing', 'page' => '2', 'rowCount' => '10' }
```

And then in ajax request, pass the `clientInfo` to `data` property:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ...,
  method: "post",
  data: clientInfo ,
  success: function(){

 }
})
```

In the Controller, when you dd the payload, it's gonna look like this:

```
array:6 [
  "customer_name" => "Arely Torphy II"
  "customer_email" => "lexi.kulas@jacobson.net"
  "customer_phone" => "1-448-897-3923 x1937"
  "address" => "1422 Ellie Stream Suite 859"
  "post" => "37167"
  "company_name" => "company"
]
```

Now, you can easily retrieve any data you'd like to.